# XSLT - Best practice for moving specific attributes around

Tags: xslt

I was looking for some guidance on how best to approach my issue.

I have an XML document like the following but on a larger scale.

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table Attri1="Attri1Val" Attri2="Attri2Val" Attri3="Attri3Val" Attri4="Attri4Val" Attri5="Attri5Val" Attri6="Attri6Val" Attri7="Attri7" />
</NewDataSet>
```

I need to move certain attributes from the Table node, for example `Attri2` and `Attri5` into elements within the Table node, however I need to leave the rest of the attributes as they are.

What would be the best way to approach this? The data scale is about 3-4 times that shown.

EDIT:
Expected output:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table Attri1="Attri1Val" Attri3="Attri3Val" Attri4="Attri4Val" Attri6="Attri6Val" Attri7="Attri7">
    <Attri2>Attri2Val</Attri2>
    <Attri5>Attri5Val</Attri5>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

The complexity is not really the issue, more the scale of the data and what is the best way to deal with it.

Comment: This doesn't sound too complicted, but can you show a bit more of your XML. You mention about "elements within the Table node" but your sample has no child nodes for the Table element. If you could show this, along with your expected output, then that should make it much clearer what you actually need to achieve. Thanks!

Comment: Which version of XSLT are you using?

Comment: 1.0, sorry should've mentioned earlier.

Comment: Mike, You may be interested to have a look at a more generic and potentially more efficient solution than the one you have accepted.

Comment: It is certainly interesting Dimitre, I just don't fancy re-writing the entire stylesheet again to implement it else I would experiment further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Table">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name() = 'Attri2') and not(name() = 'Attri5')]"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@Attri2 | @Attri5 | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Table/@Attri2 | Table/@Attri5">
 <xsl:element name="{name()}">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

[edit]
The name comparison of the attributes is a bit ugly but will probably do for your sample. What we really need is `@* execpt (@Attri2, @Attri5)`, only that is XPath 2.0. With XPath 1.0 the equivalent is

```
<xsl:template match="Table">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:variable name="all-attributes" select="@*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="to-be-transformed" select="@Attri2 | @Attri5"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$all-attributes[count(. | $to-be-transformed) != count($to-be-transformed)]"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="$to-be-transformed | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Will implement and test accordingly, will come back to you.

Comment: The above does not work on the provided test data alone, the stylesheet exceptions trying to match Attri3 because you cannot add attributes to the Table node after adding an element to it (Attri2)

Comment: You are right, I forgot about that problem with all attributes needing to be added first. In that case a further template is needed, I edited the post with a template matching `Table` that tries to make sure we first process all attributes that remain attributes, then the ones to be transformed into elements.

Comment: This seems to be working correctly, it will take a while to fully implement but I will let you know the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

**This generic transformation can handle any set of attributes, with any length, whose names can be specified externally to the transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pToTransform" select="'|Attri2|Attri5|'"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Table">
  <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select=
         "@*[not(contains($pToTransform, concat('|',name(),'|')))] | node()"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="makeElement"
        select="@*[contains($pToTransform, concat('|',name(),'|'))]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@*" mode="makeElement">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied to the provided XML document:**

```
<NewDataSet>
    <Table Attri1="Attri1Val" Attri2="Attri2Val"
    Attri3="Attri3Val" Attri4="Attri4Val"
    Attri5="Attri5Val" Attri6="Attri6Val"
    Attri7="Attri7" />
</NewDataSet>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<NewDataSet>
   <Table Attri1="Attri1Val" Attri3="Attri3Val" Attri4="Attri4Val" Attri6="Attri6Val" Attri7="Attri7">
      <Attri2>Attri2Val</Attri2>
      <Attri5>Attri5Val</Attri5>
   </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```